# SQL Query to Retrieve the details of those employees who works in a department having head count more than 5

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have the following Table.

```
                        STAFF


   STAFFNO STAFFNAME  DESIGNATI     SALARY     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
      1000 Rajesh     Manager        35000          1
      1001 Manoj      Caretaker    7420.35          1
      1002 Swati      HR             22500          3
      1003 Suresh     HR             23400          3
      1004 Najim      Mangager       17200          2
      1006 Ritesh     Prgrmr         23500          2
      1005 Nisha      Prgrmr         24852          1
      1007 Rajib      Security        6547          3
      1008 Neeraj     Prgrmr         17300          1
      1009 Dushant    Prgrmr         16500          1
      1010 Pradyut    Manager        26300          2
      1011 Manisha    Prgrmr         21500          2
      1012 Janak      Security        8500          2
```

Now I want to run a query on oracle (SQL*Plus) in which I can retrieve the details of those employees who works in a department having 5 or more head count.(e.g. deptno. 1 and deptno. 2 have 5 employees working in them)

Can you help me with the Oracle query to retrieve that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I was trying this `select* from staff where count(staffno) group by deptno having count(staffno)>=5;` but this is giving an error that group function is not allowed here.

Comment: You should always put in whatever query you tried. It helps identify where you went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need create a sub query or perform a `JOIN`.

With a `JOIN` first you need to know what department has more that 5 employees.

```
 SELECT DEPTNO
 FROM STAFF
 GROUP BY DEPTNO
 HAVING  COUNT(*) >= 5
```

Now you join both result

```
SELECT S.*
FROM STAFF S
JOIN  ( SELECT DEPTNO
        FROM STAFF
        GROUP BY DEPTNO
        HAVING  COUNT(*) >= 5 ) F
ON S.DEPTNO = F.DEPTNO
```

Subquery version:

```
SELECT S.*
FROM STAFF S
WHERE S.DEPTNO IN ( SELECT DEPTNO
                    FROM STAFF
                    GROUP BY DEPTNO
                    HAVING  COUNT(*) >= 5 )
```

Comment: Thanks @Juan, worked like a charm and the subquery version was easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the employee detail, then you actually want an analytic function:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*, count(*) over (partition by deptno) as deptcnt
      from staff
     ) s
where deptcnt >= 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
SELECT * FROM STAFF WHERE DEPTNO IN 
(SELECT DEPTNO FROM STAFF GROUP BY DEPTNO HAVING COUNT(*)>4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is using a join (because no one has) it may allow you to change your BI rules easier....

```
SELECT S.*
FROM STAFF S
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DEPTNO, COUNT(*) AS C
  FROM STAFF
  GROUP BY DEPTNO
) AS D_COUNTS ON S.DEPTNO = D_COUNT.DEPTNO
WHERE D_COUNTS.C >= 5
```

or as a CTE

```
WITH D_COUNTS AS
(
  SELECT DEPTNO, COUNT(*) AS C
  FROM STAFF
  GROUP BY DEPTNO
)
SELECT S.*
FROM STAFF S
LEFT JOIN D_COUNTS ON S.DEPTNO = D_COUNT.DEPTNO
WHERE D_COUNTS.C >= 5
```